# How do I extract values from clean url?

Tags: php, regex

in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it changes url site.com/user/12 to site.com?q=user/12

now in my php I can read value of 'q' param.

What I want is to write some mapping util

```
utils::map('user/{u}',function($u){
  //do some thing
});
```

What cud be the best way to do this?
More precisely, how can i extract value of 'u' from url?
Regex or any string fucntion?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like Yii or CI ?

Comment: no I am not using any framework, and cant use any here too, everything is ready except this one, just need solution for this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex: `user\/(\d+)`

Here's an [example on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/nF9bO1) of the same. You can access the {u} part from the regex match using $1.